# "No module named import" when trying to use import function python

Tags: python, macos, api, import, module

I am trying to import some packages from API modules I have already installed in python however I cannot seem to get the import function to work at all.

Here are three examples of the code I am trying to execute (I am using the code terminal on my MacOS):

```
python3 -m import pytrends
python -m import pandas as pd
python3 -m from pytrends.request import TrendReq
```

But every time I execute any of these it reads the first word after '-m' as a filename that it thinks I am trying to retrieve. I figure I must be doing something stupid but any help would be greatly appreciated nonetheless. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-m` executes a module, it does not import it. Importing a module from the command line doesn't make sense anyway. What are you planning to do even if you can import it? It will be lost as soon as the command terminates.

Comment: The `-m` runs a module as the main program. You probably want `-c`.  `python3 -c "import os"`.

Comment: @Selcuk I am trying to use the pytrends API in python, according to the tutorial I've been following it instructs me to import them as packages after installing them as modules.

Comment: @Keith thank you! I did not consider ```-m``` as a variable in this. ```-c``` seems to have made some progress, will follow along with it.